# Github copilot proxy error on visual studio code

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I installed github copilot in vsc and it gives me this error

> Sign in failed: Proxy Authentication Required ( Per il completamento della richiesta Ã¨ necessaria l'autorizzazione di Forefront TMG. Impossibile accedere al filtro proxy Web.  )

Is this fixable?